Custom plugin development with paypal subscription method
I'm rying to create PayPal subscription button inside my custom plugin but there are some queries to resolv first, I only have single plan right now for ex. Test Plan.

What will be better ? Payment button or SDK ?
If i use PayPal library than how can i prevent Client ID and Secret ?
I used payment button once to test, It's working fine and payment process also as expected but how can i restrict content of my plugin ? Like if subscription is expired than please renew it again msg or something like that.

